# Moment + Requirejs confusion with require

Tags: requirejs, momentjs

I can't get my app to see moment, I have tried everything I've seen via googling and on stackoverflow.

```
require.config({
baseUrl: 'app',

paths: {
    'angular': '../lib/angular.min',
    'angularMessages': '../lib/angular-messages.min',
    'angularResource': '../lib/angular-resource.min',

    //moment stuff
    "moment":          '../lib/moment',
    'momentLocale':    '../lib/moment-with-locales',
    'angular-moment':  '../lib/angular-moment.min',



},
shim: {
  angular: {
      exports : 'angular'
  },
  "angular-moment": { "deps": ["momentjs"] }

}
});




require([
'app',
'angular'], function (app) {
  require([
 'moment',
 'momentjs',
 'momentLocale',
 'angular-moment'], function () {
   app.init();
  });
});
```

Yet however I can get this to run no problems

```
// load moment.js as moment
require(['moment'], function(moment) {
  // test if moment is loaded
  alert(moment().format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
});
```

Note I stripped out the other stuff in my require js as there are no problems whatever with those resources.

Comment: What error message are you getting on the console? When you look at the network requests is there anything that does not load? Edit your question with this information. Also, what's the deal with `moment` and `momentjs`? Whenever I've used `moment`, I've just loaded `moment`. (I get the point of `momentLocale` and `angular-moment` but I see what `momentjs` would be.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion that was part of a fix I tried where I defined moment in a module called momentjs (something I read on github).
`define(["moment"], function (moment) {
        moment.lang('en');
        moment().format();
        return moment;
    });`